# Do only AWS DDB batch requests employ a retry strategy?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I read that [each AWS SDK implements retry logic automatically](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.RetryAndBackoff). I currently have code that uses the [`DynamoDBMapper`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) class provided by the Java AWS SDK. Currently, I am using the `load()/save()/delete()` functions provided by that class.
However, looking at the code for the `DynamoDBMapper` class I cannot find the retry logic for the [`load()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/f19bdb30177106b5d6394223a40a382b87adf742/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L413)/[`save()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/f19bdb30177106b5d6394223a40a382b87adf742/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L507)/[`delete()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/f19bdb30177106b5d6394223a40a382b87adf742/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L1038) functions and only see the retry logic for batch calls like [`batchLoad()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/f19bdb30177106b5d6394223a40a382b87adf742/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L1364) (retry logic can be clearly found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/f19bdb30177106b5d6394223a40a382b87adf742/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L1482)).

Do only batch functions like `batchLoad()/batchWrite()` have retry logic implemented for DDB in the Java AWS SDK? Where does retries occur for non-batch calls?

Thanks!